# Quotation text qualifier for ingest into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, csv

I have a csv formatted as follows:

```
col1|col2|col3
"a"|"\"a\""|"b"
```

When I use the text qualifier with the import wizard - col2 turns into ""a"

I am okay with this in the preview but when I try to import the data I get the following warning:

> column delimiter for col2 cannot been found

Would anyone be able to help

Cheers

Duane

Comment: CSV = comma-separated value. So no, you don't have CSV at all. It is not clear what your column separate is, but it is certainly not a comma. Is it the pipe symbol? What do you expect as values in how many columns for import purposes?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried printing out the value you are trying to get? I don't think you need the | |.   ''a'''''a''''b''' might work

Comment: looking at some of the comments, using a CSV import you probably need the following :  "a","\a\ ","b"  . I am confused about what you want the columns to be. The previous would result in col1|col2|col3       a|\a\ |b